# How to store OAuth credentials in Flask cookie session securely?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, google-oauth

I'm currently working on a small tool which uses a login based on *Google OAuth 2.0*. My server is written in *Python* and uses *Flask*.

Following Google's Python implementation, the credentials are stored in a session object:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python

I'm confused by the fact that the session object also stores the `client_secret` which is then transmitted to the end-user as part of the cookie. As far as I understand, a Flask session cookie should never be used to store sensitive data.

Any thoughts on this? What's a secure way of storing all necessary data in a session to make multiple queries to the Google APIs?

I have seen approaches using *Flask-Session* but I'd like to avoid running a separate Redis/memcached service or storing all cookies on disk.

Thanks & best regards,
Fabian

Comment: Oh, no. We shouldn't store client secrets in session. Checkout demos for Authlib: https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client There is a demo for Google login.